# Intel HAXM error in VMWare Fusion - Unable to run Android Apps

Tags: android, emulation, intel, haxm

I am trying to start the Android emulation device inside a Windows 7 x64 VM running inside VMWare Fusion.

Below are the details:

```
Host OS: OSX 10.12.6
Virtualization Software: VMWare Fusion 8.5.10
Guest OS: Windows 7 x64
```

When I start the emulation device, I receive the following error message:

```
emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_25

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The device details are:

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: Nexus_5X_API_25
  Device: Nexus 5X (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_25.avd
  Target: Google Play (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis_playstore/x86
    Skin: nexus_5x
  Sdcard: 100M
```

Intel haxm-check.exe shows that both VT and NX support are available inside the VM:

```
VT support -- yes
NX support -- yes
```

I already installed the Intel HAXM and I can see it installed in the list of programs as well.

I checked the Virtual Machine settings and the following option is enabled as well:

```
Enable Hypervisor applications in this virtual machine

Support for Intel VT-x/EPT in the virtual machine
```

So, how can I resolve this error message?

It seems that I have already configured all the necessary options required to successfully run the emulation device inside VMWare Fusion.

Comment: Running an emulator inside an emulator-  even if its possible (and I'm reasonable certain it isn't as they'd both try to be a hypervisor), your performance is going to majorly suck.  I'd suggest ditching the top level hypervisor or using a real device, this is not going to go well.

Comment: When you say running an emulator inside another emulator, you are referring to VMWare Fusion software as an emulator, do I understand that correct?

Comment: I actually remember getting this running a while back properly but for some reason, the device won't start now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run Android in a VM?

Download an ISO from [Android-x86](https://www.android-x86.org/) and install it.

Another way would be to use Microsoft's [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/). Despite the name, you can run it stand-alone too.